# Adding momentum term in online back propagation weight update?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation, momentum, feed-forward

I have implemented the ANN for two-layer network, I need to modify my weight update code with momentum, but i need to know how can i update it. below is the code snap of only weight update. The below code updates weight for each example it has seen, The hiddenWights are the hidden layer weight and the outputWeights are output layer weights.

```
 for examplen = 1: nTrainingExamples
           inputVector = inputs(:,examplen);
           HiddenLayerOutput = sigmoid( hiddenWeights * inputVector);
           OutputLayerOutput = sigmoid( outputWeights * HiddenLayerOutput);

           l2_error = OutputLayerOutput - targets(:, examplen);
           l2_delta = learningRates(1, i) .* (OutputLayerOutput .* (1 - OutputLayerOutput)) .* l2_error;
           l2_v = mu * l2_v - l2_delta * t;

           l1_delta = learningRates(1, i) .* (HiddenLayerOutput .* (1 - HiddenLayerOutput)) .* (outputWeights' * l2_delta);
           l1_v = mu * l1_v - l1_delta * t;
           % weights = weights + v
           outputWeights = outputWeights + (l2_v*HiddenLayerOutput');
           hiddenWeights = hiddenWeights + (l1_v*inputVector');
       end
```

Comment: What kind of momentum do you want to implement? A classic or a Nestrov one?

Comment: I just need to add momentum update, i don't know exactly what the difference between classic or a nestrow?

Comment: Check out this post : http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179915/whats-the-difference-between-momentum-based-gradient-descent-and-nesterovs-ac

Comment: So from above post I need momentum based gradient descent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our conversation it turn out that you want to implement a classic momentum method (not Nestrov). So you need an additional parameter - the speed `v` and *time* `t` and *momentum* `mu` constants.

At the beginning of learning you should set your speed to `0` :

```
v = 0
```

and choose some value of `t` (e.g. set it to 0.1) and `mu` (e.g. 0.9).

During each iterations of training you should change your weights according to the following rule :

```
v = mu * v - delta * t
weights = weights + v
```

Parameters `mu` and `t` are meta parameters and you can find good values of them by a grid or random search.

Comment: I need to find v for both delta's separately, or use same v for both delta's?

Comment: For each delta separately.

Comment: Thank you Marcin :), i also need help in applying dropout to it, can you share any post for it?

Comment: Precise what exactly either what you want to read about (or implement) or ask another question on Stack :) Comments are only to specify your questions or answers on SO.

Comment: kindly check i have edited my question with code of momentum. Let me know if i did any mistake.